# Android - loading large bitmaps into TouchImageView

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview

I am new to Android, but have done some iOS work.  I get an error when I load a bitmap from a camera image on a Samsung S4 (4.4.4):

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFilePath, options);

imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Here imgView is a TouchImageView.  (I tried using ImageViewZoom but can't get it to import into AndroidStudio.)

I get this error:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4128x3096, max=4096x4096)
```

Coming from iOS I am amazed that Android can't load an image from the phone's own camera!  I hope there is a way that is not too hard.  It must be possible since the gallery seems to be able to do it.
The examples I see on the web (suggesting that you subsample the image) seem to miss the point.  With pan and zoom (which should be built into an ImageView) an image view is just a smaller window into a much larger image.  You should not have to fit the bitmap to the pixel size of the view. I fear that this silly advice (subsampling) reflects a serious deficiency in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I believe error message is related to OpenGL not Android. GPU may put restrictions on max texture resolution. For your case that is 4096x4096 pixels. Developers are advised to load scaled down version into UI because it is not reasonable to view large image in limited screen display such as phone. More info about this can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

If you need to view large image at actual size then you can just draw visible part of image.

Comment: The iPhone is a phone and has no such restrictions.

Comment: Android since Honeycomb use GPU hardware acceleration for displaying everything that show up in the screen. So `View` basically just 3D polygon with texture attached to it. It is done by Android mostly transparent to developers which in iOS, AFAIK that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "no easy way".  I suspected this, but had to check to make sure.  I did find that setting `android:hardwareAccelerated = "false"` in the manifest allowed large bitmaps to be loaded, but then the app would soon crash out of memory.  Interesting that the lack of hardware acceleration did not seem to make much of a difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

My library is designed to solve this problem, it subsamples the image initially and then loads higher resolution tiles as you zoom in. If you look closely you can see that most Android gallery apps do the same thing.

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: This looks like a good library.  Unfortunately, in addition to just display  my app needs access to the whole bitmap for image processing.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get the maximum texture size and scale image if any of dimensions is larger.

Unfortunately I do not remember where I got this snippet (it is not mine).
It works fine for this purpose in production for quite a while now.

```java
public int provideMaxTextureSize() {
        EGL10 egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();

        EGLDisplay dpy = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
        int[] vers = new int[2];
        egl.eglInitialize(dpy, vers);

        int[] configAttr = {
                EGL10.EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE, EGL10.EGL_RGB_BUFFER,
                EGL10.EGL_LEVEL, 0,
                EGL10.EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL10.EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
                EGL10.EGL_NONE
        };
        EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
        int[] numConfig = new int[1];
        egl.eglChooseConfig(dpy, configAttr, configs, 1, numConfig);
        if (numConfig[0] == 0) {
            // TROUBLE! No config found.
        }
        EGLConfig config = configs[0];

        int[] surfAttr = {
                EGL10.EGL_WIDTH, 64,
                EGL10.EGL_HEIGHT, 64,
                EGL10.EGL_NONE
        };
        EGLSurface surf = egl.eglCreatePbufferSurface(dpy, config, surfAttr);
        final int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;  // missing in EGL10
        int[] ctxAttrib = {
                EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 1,
                EGL10.EGL_NONE
        };
        EGLContext ctx = egl.eglCreateContext(dpy, config, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, ctxAttrib);
        egl.eglMakeCurrent(dpy, surf, surf, ctx);
        int[] maxSize = new int[1];
        GLES10.glGetIntegerv(GLES10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxSize, 0);
        egl.eglMakeCurrent(dpy, EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE,
                EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
        egl.eglDestroySurface(dpy, surf);
        egl.eglDestroyContext(dpy, ctx);
        egl.eglTerminate(dpy);

        return maxSize[0];
    }
```